# local variable 'fight_run' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, loops, indentation

ive been looking around but ive been unable to fix this error.
also as a side problem before this error the program would always print your week was average nothing much happened and the other 2 variables that could of happened didn't

this is all in python

```
from random import randint
import time
money = 2000
week = 0
def stockmarket():
    global money
    global week
    stock = int(randint(1,50))
    fight_random = int(randint(1,4))
    fight = int(randint(1,100))
    gain_lose = int(randint(1,2))
    win_lose_var = int(randint(1,30))
    luck = int(0)
    if money > 10000 :
        print ("""congratulations you beat the game by earning 10,000
        now that you have so much money you can go back to your life as a hip hop artist """)
        time.sleep(4)
        print("it took you ",week,"weeks's to compleate the game")
        print("can you do it faster next time")
    else:
        print(" you have gained lots of money",money,"")
        print("you must now invest it all the stock market")
        human_stock = int(input("please pick a number between 1-100 not that it matters as the markets are rigged: "))
            #need to make the user number matter 
        change1 = int(stock-40+luck)
        change2 = float (change1/100)
        change3 = float (1-change2)
        money = money * change3
        week = week+1
        print ("you have" , money,"")
        week = week +1 


 #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS!
        if fight == 3:
            print("bad luck")
            fight_run = str(input("""late at night you get approched by a bunch of bad, bad people. they attempt to mugg you but you see there is a chance to run away but you could fight
                        them and gain lots of money! do you fight or run"""))
        if fight_run == "run":
                print("you fled the scene but left some money behind which has been stolen.")
                money *=.8
                print(" ",money," ")
                stockmarket()
        if fight_run == "fight" :
               print ("you chose to fight the oncoming enemys!")
        if fight < 0 or fight > 11:
                    print("you where over powered by your enemys and died")
                    time.sleep(5)
                    quit()
        elif fight <10 and fight >80 :
                    win_lose = int(input("the fight is close and you are both weak. /n please pick and number between 1 and 30 for a chance to gain money!"))
        elif gain_lose == 1:
                print("you deafeated your attacckers and take there money (its not a crime if no one saw)")
                money_fight_win = (win_lose/100)+ 1
                money = money * money_fight_win
                print ("",money,"")
        elif gain_lose == 2 :
                print ("your attacker won and they took your money luckly you hide some just before the fight ")
                money_fight_lose = (win_lose/100)+ 1 - (winlose/50)
                money = money * money_fight_lose

        else :
                print("you mortaliy wounded the atackers (cause ur dench m8) and took their money") 
                money = money *1.5
                #loop
                stockmarket()

        if fight == 4:
            print ("you found a lucky penny and added it to your penny collection")
            luck = +1
        elif fight == 1 or 2:
            print("your week was average nothing much happened")
            #loop
            stockmarket()


#gets program to start
stockmarket()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is indentation level.  So, if fight != 3, then fight_run is never declared or set.  So when you check fight_run in the next if statement there is a chance that it might not exist.  Fix your indentation so it reads.

```
if fight == 3:
    print("bad luck")
    fight_run = str(input("""late at night you get approched by a bunch of bad, bad people. they attempt to mugg you but you see there is a chance to run away but you could fight them and gain lots of money! do you fight or run"""))
    if fight_run == "run":
        print("you fled the scene but left some money behind which has been stolen.")
        money *=.8
        print(" ",money," ")
        stockmarket()
    if fight_run == "fight" :
        print ("you chose to fight the oncoming enemys!")
```

This way, if fight == 3, then the player is approached, then depending on the player choice he can fight or run.  Addressing this will get you to your next error, your code has a bunch of issues, including some more indentation level issues like this one.

Regarding the other issue you mentioned, when you do `elif fight == 1 or 2:`, that will always be true because testing 2 as a boolean will always be true.  This would need to be `elif fight == 1 or fight == 2:`.

Also, as Robert said in his answer, you have several fall through situations here where the user can input an instruction that will not match any checks.  You should always verify that you the instruction cannot fall through and do nothing.

Comment: I just deleted a similar answer since this one is more clear. Also, what if I typed "pee my pants" instead of "run" or "fight"?

Comment: You made a good point about input validation though.  He is currently not performing mutually exclusive input checks or validating that the input is digestable.

Comment: Ok I undeleted my deleted answer even though there is a lot of overlap.  :)

Answer (score 1):

What if the value of fight is 1?

Then `if fight == 3` is false, so the creation of the variable `fight_run` is skipped, so the variable `fight_run` doesn't exist. Then you are testing `if fight_run == "run"` and you are being told `fight_run` doesn't exist.

I think what you want to do is to indent the code:

```
if fight_run == "run":
    print("you fled the scene but left some money behind which has been stolen.")
    money *=.8
    print(" ",money," ")
    stockmarket()
if fight_run == "fight" :
    print ("you chose to fight the oncoming enemys!")
```

So that it is part of the `if fight == 3` block.

Instead of a long sequence of 'if's, I would also look at using `elif` and `else` and maybe putting the input in a loop.  What if I typed "pee my pants" instead of "run" or "fight"?